# T-SQL : If login failed, then sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, linked-server

Goal: Write a T-SQL statement that checks for login permissions on a linked server db, and then updates a column value based on login result.

Sudo-ish code:

```
@Source = linked server connection string

while true

if exists(select [Something] from [@Source])
update [Table] set [Column] = 1
else
update [Table] set [Column] = 0

@Source = next linked server
```

The idea is that if I cannot get a record from the table, then I do not have access. When I execute this query using actual T-SQL, the login failed error occurs Is there any was of accomplishing this, using T-SQL? Currently I manually check and update.

Comment: what language is this?  connection string makes no sense in tsql

Comment: if you are asking if you are going in the correct direction the answer is no -- you should not use if statements in sql.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking if you are going in the right direction, I would say no.  Here is sudo-ish code:

```
-- perform connection to external server.

-- make update
update <table>
   SET <field to indicate result> = <result>
 WHERE <filter to select row>
```

Here is another hint.  `<result>` could be something like

```
    SET <field> = CASE WHEN @login = 'OK' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a linked server you'll get an error if you try to `select` and you don't have permissions. This is not something that can be done with a single statement. I assume you're already using a stored procedure if you are using `IF`s.

You can use the function [`sp_testlinkedserver`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189809.aspx) which was designed for this (sort of, still relies on exception handling). You still need to use a `TRY/CATCH` like

```
declare @TestedServerReturnValue int
BEGIN TRY
    EXEC @TestedServerReturnValue = sys.sp_testlinkedserver @ServerName
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SET @TestedServerReturnValue = @@error
END CATCH

IF @TestedServerReturnValue = 0 BEGIN
    Print 'Success'
END
ELSE BEGIN
    print 'Could not connect'
END
```

Comment: This is getting closer to what I am asking.. So the curious thing is that I have Login capabilities to the server, but my permissions end at the Db level. So using the sp_testlinkedserver will still deliver a successful result.

Comment: Basically I have multiple servers, each with a metadata db. The metadata db has the same schema across all servers. My goal is to retrieve the last three months of metadata from each linked server, and place the metadata in single table on my server. I am using a sp to accomplish this. When looping through each linked server, the whole sp fails when I encounter a server for which I cannot query the table. So I wish to create a statement that basically skips the linked server if the query will fail due to permission issues.

Comment: When I've done this I've used a cursor to loop through the list of servers, test the connection, then test the select statements. Every failure point is in a TRY/CATCH when recovery is possible so that I can proceed with the rest of the servers.